# Disable radio button in Struts 1

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

I have a yes or no radio buttons which I want to disable or enable based on the value of the `booleanProperty`.

If `booleanProperty`'s value is"Y" then the `logic:equal` will bring me to the code where I want to disable the Yes or No radio button.

If the `BooleanProperty` is "N" then the logic:equal will bring me to the code where I do not disable the Yes or No radio button.

There is no disable property in struts `<html:radio>` can you kindly help me do the functionality. I have described above in my pseudo code below as well.

```
              <logic:equal name="myForm" property="booleanProperty" value="Y">
                   <td class="Label"><bean:message key="Label.hs"  bundle="Messages" /></td>
                  <td>Yes: <html:radio property="hs" value="Y"
                      styleClass="Radio" **disable = "true"** /> No: <html:radio property="hs"
                      value="N" styleClass="Radio" **disable = "true"**/></td>  
               </logic:equal>

               <logic:equal name="myForm" property="booleanProperty" value="N">
                   <td class="Label"><bean:message key="Label.hs"  bundle="Messages" /></td>
                  <td>Yes: <html:radio property="hs" value="Y"
                      styleClass="Radio"   /> No: <html:radio property="hs"
                      value="N" styleClass="Radio" /></td>  
               </logic:equal>
```

SOLUTION:-

Basically I wanted to retain the value of the booleanProperty  which I received from the Action class.  The idea is to deactivate the radio button based on the value of the booleanPrpoerty. I removed the Logic:equal tag as Logic:equal gets compiled on the server side and decides what to display on compile time.  I wanted something which would decide at runtime, something to do with java script.

So i changed the above radio button HTML to

```
Yes: <html:radio property="booleanRadio" value="Y" styleClass="Radio" /> 
No: <html:radio property="booleanRadio"  value="N" styleClass="Radio" />
```

I created a hidden property field like below.

```
<html:hidden property="booleanProperty" />
```

and wrote a java script like this

```
frm = document.mainForm
   function booleanPropertyValue()
          {
          if(frm.booleanProperty.value == 'Y')
          {
          radioGroupDisabled(frm.booleanRadio, true);
          }
          else
          {
          radioGroupDisabled(frm.booleanRadio, false);
          }
          }
```

Comment: There isn't such property. Use html code disabled attribute.

Comment: Thank you Roman C, I used HTML and got it disabled.

Comment: Hi, I am passing the property value for the above 'booleanProperty' from my struts action class as 'Y' or 'N' according to my business logic.  In the strut's DynaValidatorActionForm i have put 'N' as initial for 'booleanProperty'. So when the form is not filled properly the refreshed page is going back to 'N' and the passed value from my action class is not considered :( any suggestion how do i maintain the passed value from my action class and assign it to my booleanProperty if there is a validation error on the form.

Comment: If it's going back to `'N'` then it's filled properly, otherwise it will be `null`. You have not posted a complete code example, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.  Basically I wanted to retain the value of the booleanProperty  which I received from the Action class.  If the form is not filled properly I was loosing the value.  So I created a hidden property field like below.

Comment: this is a different problem which retains the value, from another that receives it, another problem is to let the user to choose which value he needs to submit. All that difficulties already solved  with Struts2.